# AKS, pulling docker image failed with error: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to deploy spring boot app to azure kubernetes cluster using pipelines setup in azure devops git repo. But the aks deployment is failing with the following error:

> Failed to pull image "sapcemission.azurecr.io/spaceship": [rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for
> sapcemission.azurecr.io/spaceship:latest not found: manifest unknown:
> manifest tagged by "latest" is not found, rpc error: code = Unknown
> desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https://sapcemission.azurecr.io/v2/spaceship/manifests/latest:
> unauthorized: authentication required, visit
> https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.]

My project is a spring boot multi-module project containing two modules. I'm trying to deploy them both. What am I doing wrong here?

azure-pipelines.yml

```
# Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# Build and push image to Azure Container Registry; Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'd5d300b9-b22f-4b38-a5c8-35526548a630'
  imageRepositoryCommandCenter: 'commandcenter'
  imageRepositorySpaceShip: 'spaceship'
  containerRegistry: 'sapcemissipion.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePathCommandCenter: '**/command-center/Dockerfile'
  dockerfilePathSpaceShip: '**/space-ship/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'sapcemission13564b3d-auth'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Maven@3
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
        effectivePomSkip: false
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an command center image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepositoryCommandCenter)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePathCommandCenter)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an space ship image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepositorySpaceShip)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePathSpaceShip)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
          
    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'spacemission-1550.kube-system'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.yml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepositoryCommandCenter):$(tag)
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepositorySpaceShip):$(tag)
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: commandcenter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: commandcenter
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: commandcenter
          image: sapcemission.azurecr.io/commandcenter
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080


---


apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spaceship
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spaceship
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spaceship
          image: sapcemission.azurecr.io/spaceship
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: commandcenter
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 8080
    selector:
        app: commandcenter

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: spaceship
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
        - port: 8080
    selector:
        app: spaceship
```

Comment: The actual error is `unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information`. Did you look at that link?  You're creating an image pull secret, but I don't see you specifying it in your Kubernetes manifests. If you're using AKS and ACR, you can integrate the two so no image pull secrets are required. What have you tried to do to solve the authentication problem?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows the authentication is required. And I see you create the `imagePullSecret` so that you just need to add the imagePullSecret in the deployment of your YAML file like this:

```
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: commandcenter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: commandcenter
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: commandcenter
          image: sapcemission.azurecr.io/commandcenter
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:                             # here
      - name: "sapcemission13564b3d-auth"
---
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spaceship
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spaceship
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spaceship
          image: sapcemission.azurecr.io/spaceship
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
      imagePullSecrets:                             # here                             
      - name: "sapcemission13564b3d-auth"
```

And the error also shows the image tag not found. So you need also to check if the tag really exists.

Answer (score 0):

Following docs here [Authenticate with Azure Container Registry from Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration)

> When you're using Azure Container Registry (ACR) with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), an authentication mechanism needs to be established. This operation is implemented as part of the CLI and Portal experience by granting the required permissions to your ACR.

The easiest way it would be:

`az aks update -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr <acrName>`

but this require:

> - Owner or Azure account administrator role on the Azure subscription
> - Azure CLI version 2.7.0 or later
>
> To avoid needing an Owner or Azure account administrator role, you can configure a service principal manually or use an existing service principal to authenticate ACR from AKS. For more information, see ACR authentication with service principals or Authenticate from Kubernetes with a pull secret.